# SwipeLeft Gesture not working on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView`. I don't have "`canEditRowAtIndexPath`" implemented.

Following code works on controllers which don't have UITableView but does not work on controller with UITableView.

I did try `setCancelsTouchesInView = NO` on gestureRecognizer.

In container view controller, I have implemented:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandlerLeft:)];
[leftGestureRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftGestureRecognizer];
```

Comment: Add UISwipeGestureRecognizer to tableView cell rather than UITableView or other view

Comment: @Md.MuzahidulIslam this does what I want. Is this the standard practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better try adding `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to your `UITableViewCell` rather than `UITableView`
Try adding this in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
let recognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: collectionView, action: #selector(handleGesture))
        recognizer.direction = .left
        recognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        cell .addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

func handleGesture(){

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `delegate`

```
leftGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
```

Then add the `delegate` method :

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```